# My react component is failing due to component rendering before state is set. How can I resolve this issue?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, google-cloud-firestore, next.js

I don't know if what I'm trying to do is possible but I've been trying for a week now and I feel like I'm so close but I just can't get there. Maybe it's not possible? Anyway, using reactjs and next js (I'm new to coding so I'll try my best to explain clearly what I'm trying to do):

I have a webapp that shows user transactions (from an api that I don't own/didn't create). I added like/ comment functionality to this app using firestore. Basically every time someone comments or likes a post their **username** and **like/comment** get's stored in my database along with the **post id** (which came originally from the api - which again - I didn't create). I thought it would be nice to let users know when someone likes or comments on their transaction and the way I planed to do this was like this :

First,  query (my database - firestore) all posts that have a like or a comment, then set that **post_ID** in state

Next, I'll loop through all of those **post_ID's** and use them to complete a URL for an api fetch. You see, the api ends like the /sales/{saleID} .... which **sale ID** is the same as my **post ID** but the name varies because I changed it for my data base. That fetch will return a bunch of arrays , each of which show **a seller/buyer**.

Then I can take each **buyer** and **seller** and create a notification that says something like "hey {seller} {buyer}, someone liked your post. And I would only show this message if it's the current user and the current user matches the buyer or seller.

So part 3 I haven't done yet but I'm pretty sure I can pull off - I've done something similar. Part 1 seems to be working great! Part 2 is where I *think* I'm failing. I keep getting a "failed to fetch" but I think this is because some of the arrays are returning empty. Could you guys help me by reviewing my code and letting me know what you think? Like I said, I'm new, so I'm sure I wrote a lot of dumb stuff in there but this is a work in progress and a lot of stuff I did was me trying things out. Here is the code:

Also, here are some issues I've identified:

when I **console.log(posts)**- It returns an empty array twice, then it returns the array of postsID's but multiple times. Sometimes 3 times, sometimes 7 times. This number seems to vary though but 3 and 7 are what I keep seeing.

when I **console.log(postID)**- same idea

when I **console.log(postData)**- very similar. I get an empty array a couple of time, then I get an array for the post ID. Here is the strange thing. Ideally, this is supposed to contain an array of transaction info for each post ID that was used, but instead I get an empty array, then another, then my transaction arrays start coming in but a lot are duplicates.

-So seems to me that the issue is at the very beginning, the postID's being returned so many times.

I also found something else. If I comment everything out in the return and just put some dummy text, and then I console log **postData** (which is the most important item), then everything seems to work perfectly: I get an empty array a time or two then I get on array listed per post ID. So I'm thinking that the issue is that this component is failing because it's crashing before it's done rendering. So it's trying to return something that's not there yet (the **postData.map....**)

```
function UserNotifications() {
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);
  const [postData, setPostData] = useState([]);
  const postID = posts.map((post) => post.data().likePostID);

  //------------ STEP 1: GET DATA FROM FIREBASE AND USE DATA ON API -------------------//

  useEffect(() => {
    onSnapshot(
      query(collection(db, 'Feed Posts'), orderBy('timestamp', 'desc')),
      (snapshot) => setPosts(snapshot.docs)
    );
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (posts.length != 0) {
      postID.map(async (likePostID) => {
        const response = await fetch(
          `https://proton.api.atomicassets.io/atomicmarket/v1/sales/${likePostID}`
        );
        const { data } = await response.json();
        setPostData(data);
      });
    }
  }, [posts]);
  console.log(postData);

  //----------------------------------- STEP 2: RETURN ----------------------------------//

  return (
    <>
      {' '}
      notifications coming soon
      {/* {postData.map((result) => {
        const { buyer, seller } = result;

        if (seller || buyer) {
          return <> hello {buyer}</>;
        }
      })} */}
    </>
  );
}

export default UserNotifications;
```

Answer (score 1):

Rendering virtually *always* happens multiple times in React, and it is up to you to prevent issues caused by uninitialized data, which is the case here.

A simple way to do so is by adding another `return`, just above the `return` that you already have, as follows:

```
if (!postData)
   return null;
```

You need to do this for all variables that can be empty (or otherwise invalid) at any time during rendering.